# jQuery text() function not accepting input.val()

Tags: jquery

I'd like to set up a preview area that shows what some inputted text looks like in situ. However, I'm struggling to get this jQuery function with text() to work.

whilst this works (displays "some sample text" in #preview when the form is submitted:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
              $("#preview").text("some sample text").show();
              return false;
            });
```

this doesn't work, and shows nothing when I try to take the contents of the text field and use that instead in the preview box:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
              $("#preview").text($("input:first").val()).show();
              return false;
            });
```

Any idea why? Probably dead simple and I'm just missing it.

Comment: If you `console.log($("input:first"))` do you actually get an element, and if you do, does it have a value?

Comment: From your description your jquery works fine, as long as your html is set up correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/Jwh5z/ Perhaps you can share your html or recreate the problem in jsfiddle and share that?

Comment: This piece of code works fine as I can see, maybe your input has no value added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine in a fiddle. Make sure `#preview` has a declared height and width, otherwise it may not be visually distinct.

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/js4XU/

Comment: thanks for this; it may have had something to do with the lack of a defined height/width.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I rewrote this as more of a "live preview", and used the `keyup()` function to capture the input's val instead of requesting after the form submit.